# Assigning variables to lists - c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a program that estimates energy usage. I have a list of appliances and have created a class for them:

```
List<Appliances> appliancesList = new List<Appliances>      
        {
            new Appliances("Toaster",6000, durationInput),
            new Appliances("Washing Machine",7000,durationInput),
        };

class Appliances
{
    public String name;
    public int energy_rating;
    public int duration;
    public Appliances(String nameInput, int energy_ratingInput, int durationInput)
    {
        name = nameInput;
        energy_rating = energy_ratingInput;
        duration = durationInput;
    }

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        durationInput = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

As you can see in the class, I have tried to create a variable that allows the user to enter the duration and then assign that value to the appropriate appliance in the list. I get a red line under 'durationInput' in the list section and the error says 'The name durationInput does not exist in the current context'

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is completely correct. Do you mean `duration`?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. That's the help I'm looking for

Comment: You don't know what are you trying to do? And they pay you for this?

Comment: I'm trying to allow the user to enter the duration of an appliance and then have that information assigned to a variable in a list. Is that possible?

Comment: @JoeWilson does your code compile..? shouldn't the declaration of `appliancesList` be defined inside of the class..? also if you are going to show code and or variables ...please show all relevant code the error is correct and where do you define / declare ` new Appliances("Toaster",6000, durationInput)` meaning `durationInput`

Comment: It does compile. If it makes it any easier, you don't necessarily need to refer to my exact code. I'm just wondering if it's even possible to allow a user to enter information and then assign that information to a variable in a list? "washing machine" and "6000" are string and int respectively so is it possible to have a third element that's a variable?

Answer (score 2):

You should be referencing duration.  Durationinput is your parameter.  The only thing you should be doing with durationinput is setting the variable duration equal to durationinput.  Everything else should be referencing duration.

Answer (score 0):

change
    `durationInput = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);`
to
    `this.duration = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor accepts 3 parameters.

```
 public Appliances(String nameInput, int energy_ratingInput, int durationInput)
```

In your list statement, you only pass two variables.

```
new Appliances("Washing Machine",durationInput)
```

You need to either pass three variables

```
 new Appliances("Washing Machine",0,durationInput)
```

or overload your constructor.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the problem, that was just a typo. If you look at the statement above for the toaster, 3 variables have been passed. The error still occurs.

Comment: If that is the case, where do you declare your variable durationInput?

Comment: I was told to declare 'duration' instead so I've changed that. I'm just trying to assign the contents of a textbox to a variable in a list. So you don't necessarily need to refer to my exact code if that helps, I'm just looking for the theory